# After upgraded to Meteor 1.0 my app gets stuck loading when trying to run on my iOS device

Tags: cordova, meteor

My app was working fine before upgrading to Meteor 1.0

After upgrading and trying the command:

```
meteor run ios-device --mobile-server http://memri.meteor.com
```

or

```
meteor run ios-device -p 3000
```

It opens xcode, and it loads on my device like normal, but when the app opens, it just shows the spinning center wheel behind meteor wallpaper and never opens the app

When I use the command

```
meteor run ios
```

It runs just fine in the simulator. And the web-app runs completely fine as well.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have u tried meteor run ios-device -p yourIP:3000 ???

Comment: yah unfortunately not the solution

Comment: your app code is crashing? try to connect with a chrome debugger and reload the page from the console with `location.reload()` to see the errors.

Comment: It does not seem to be crashing. Everything looks normal and I can see the log from Xcode, I don't notice anything saying it is crashing. The app seems to work in the iOS simulator, how can this be if it is the app code? If it is the app code, I would be looking over it right now but I feel like since it works in the iOS simulator, and browser there is no bug in my code.

Comment: This package is responsible for the launch screen releases: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/launch-screen

Comment: if your app is small, and you can post it as a repro, please open a github ticket

Comment: same issue here, it stucks at launch screen, fine with android. the xcode debugger doesn't show anything wrong.